# Correct OAuth2.0 setup for Service Account to use Google Ads Api?

Tags: php, service, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I have created my service account, following the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-php) as best I can.  I created a JSON Key File and have used it successfully to create and refresh my access token, but when I try to call the Google Ads API using that access token I get a 401 with the message "User in the cookie is not a valid Ads user."

I am using a PHP cURL request, not the Google Client library.

My suspicion is that I have something set up incorrectly somewhere between the Master Ad account, the service account and the project in the Google Cloud Console, but I am finding the documentation confusing and unhelpful.

I submitted a question to the Google Ads API google group, and the support person said that my setup looked OK, but also admitted that he cannot see all of it from his end.

I have created the following pieces of the puzzle:
Google Ads Master Account
Developer Token
Project in Google Cloud Console
Service Account in Project
Private Key for Service Account
Set email of Master Ads Account to role of Owner of Service Account
Enabled Domain-Wide Delegation for the Service Account with scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"
Requested and received Access Token with the private key in the JSON file

Please let me know what extra details I should provide to get my issue resolved.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that when I created my Access Token, I passed the Gmail account that owns the Google Ads Manager Account to the parameter $sub, but to access Google Ads API the Service Account must impersonate a user in the domain that is registered with the Google Workspace. This point is made in the documentation, but is rather understated.

To fix the issue I granted access to the Google Ads Manager Account to an email account in the Workspace domain, and passed that email address to $sub; now I have made a successful test call to the Google Ads API.

I attach an anonymized summary of my configuration in case it helps anyone who might be reading this in the future.

[image: My Google Ads OAuth2.0 Service Account configuration]